# Zend Framework 2 FrontController Plugin

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have decided to rewrite an application that I wrote a long time ago in ZF1. A key part of this is the utilisation of a FrontController plugin that looks at a URL and if no matching route is found it will pass it on to another controller to process.
The benefit of this is it worked for all modules without having to make further changes as it was registered as a plugin for the frontcontroller.
Can someone please help as to how I could achieve the same in ZF2
Thanks in Adavance
Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you can do it in Events.

ZF2 have default events and you can attach your code(listeners) to particular event. [List of all ZF2 default events](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html#order-of-events).

You have to play around with ZF2 events/listeners to see what will be the best choice for you.

I am doing similar staff in **MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE**. Check current route, check current user permission and if user don't have permission just return different response.

There you can found great article about how to create event/listener 
"[Understanding the Zend Framework 2 event manager](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2013/05/12/understanding-the-zend-framework-2-event-manager/)".