# Apigility throttling

Tags: zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I want to build my first API using Apigility v1.1. It will be a "private" API (consumer must be auhorized through the OAuth2 to use the API). I've already read the tutorial and seen some examples, but I haven't found anything regarding to requests throttling. I want to limit the number of requests to 50 requests per login per one minute.

Does Apigility support requests throttling? And if not, where I should implement it (controller or somewhere else)? It would be nice if the throttling would be done before controller's action is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32392608/949273

Basically is the similar thing.

You will create listener attached to ZF2 Event **MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE** and on every request (before any controller) execute your logic - check no. requests  and return appropriate status/message or let user execute request.